# Property name in a type must be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 and I have the following entities:

```
public class User {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Username { get; set; }    
  public virtual ICollection<CLaim> CLaims { get; set; }
}

public class Claim {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Type { get; set; }
  public String Value { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

A few notes about these entities:

1. In User entity the Id is the PK;
2. In Claim entity the Id is a FK and is equal to User.Id;
3. In Claim entity the PK is composite from (Id, Type, Value)

So I have the following SQL for these entities:

```
create table dbo.Users
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Users_Id primary key clustered (Id),  
  Username nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Users_Username unique (Username)
);

create table dbo.Claims
(
  Id int not null,
  [Type] nvarchar (200) not null,
  Value nvarchar (200) not null,
    constraint PK_Claims_Id_Type_Value primary key (Id, [Type], Value),
);

alter table dbo.Claims
add constraint FK_CLaims_Id foreign key (Id) 
    references dbo.Users(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

Finally, the configuration of the entities are as follows:

```
internal class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
  internal UserConfiguration() : base() {
    ToTable("Users");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(x => x.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(120);
  }
}

internal class ClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Claim> {
  internal ClaimMapper() : base() {
    ToTable("Claims");
    HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.Type, x.Value });
    Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(x => x.Type).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
    Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);

    HasRequired<User>(x => x.User).WithMany(y => y.Claims).Map(z => { z.MapKey("Id"); });
  }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I try to create a user I get the following error:

> Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Id' was already defined.

Does anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`MapKey` is only used if your foreign key column is not exposed as a property in your model. But in your case it is - as property `Claim.Id`. In that case you must use `HasForeignKey` instead of `MapKey`:

```
HasRequired<User>(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(y => y.Claims)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: What do you do if it's unidirectional? Theres no HasForeignKey method off the return HasOptional/WithOptionalPrincipal

Comment: @Sam In that case I use ´MapKey´ with the string name of the field of the FK. If I get an error about the property with that name already existing then I add an ´Ignore´ for that property.

Comment: @Diana does relationship fixup and everything works when you do that "hack"?

Comment: @jbojcic It works but you have to be careful with the `Ignore`: you will have to manually fill this property when inserting, as EF does not propagate its value (because of the `Ignore`).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Slauma's answer

`HasForeignKey` is not available for 1:1, if you still need it you can simply use `WithMany` without parameters

```
HasRequired<User>(x => x.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
HasRequired(x => x.City).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CityId);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you try to use WithMany() when the id column in the first table for the FK is also that table's primary key, then you get a multiplicity error.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen also when there is a mismatch in the type of the referencing property. For example:

```
public string TipId { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public int TipId { get; set; }
```