# Property name 'ProductId' is already defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity that has a relation using the FK ProductId, I then have another relation on the same entity using the composite keys ProductId and VehicleId. This does not work. I get

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ProductId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property
>   name 'ProductId' is already defined.

Config code

```
public class BookingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Booking>
    {
        public BookingConfiguration()
        {    
            ...

            HasRequired(b => b.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.Bookings)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapKey("ProductId");
                });

            HasRequired(b => b.Vehicle)
                .WithMany(v => v.Bookings)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapKey("ProductId","VehicleId");
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: If ProductId exists in the Booking model, have you tried HasForeignKey() instead of MapKey() ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639599/entity-framework-property-name-in-a-type-must-be-unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve Greene put me on the right track, I added `ProductId` and `VehicleId` to the Entity and used

```
HasRequired(b => b.Vehicle)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(b => new {b.ProductId, b.VehicleId});
```

In a domain perspective I don't like adding the Foreign keys to the entity so if someone has a better solution please let me know.